# How to check if string contains date in specific format?

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0

I want to check if string contains date in this format 
`"Wed, Sep 2, 2015 at 6:40 AM"`.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Try to parse that as a date using the appropriate formatting string. If it throws an exception, you know it doesn't contain that format.

Comment: Better yet use `DateTime.TryParseExact` and you don't have to deal with exceptions.

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to locate this string and those with similar formats within a larger string of text? Or just testing a single string for this date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the format string that matches your date format

```
"ddd, MMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm tt"
```

And an example of is usage

```
DateTime date;

Boolean isValidDate = DateTime.TryParseExact("Wed, Sep 2, 2015 at 6:40 AM", "ddd, MMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

And this is a code snippet to extract the date string from a larger piece of text then parse it into `DateTime`

```
// example string
String input = "This page was last updated on Wed, Sep 2, 2015 at 6:40 PM";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"[a-z]{3},\s[a-z]{3}\s[0-9],\s[0-9]{4}\sat\s[0-1]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s(AM|PM)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match match = regex.Match(input);

if (match.Success)
{
    Group g = match.Groups[0];

    CaptureCollection cc = g.Captures;
    for (int j = 0; j < cc.Count; j++) 
    {
        Capture c = cc[j];
        Console.WriteLine(c.Value);

        DateTime date;
        Boolean isValidDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(c.Value, "ddd, MMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

        if(isValidDate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Alexey Moujeer it's working right .... but if string contains other words after the date and i want to check it also so did you know how will be the format i made "ddd, MMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm tt '*' " i mean with '*' any other words but it'snot working

Comment: You can first extract the date string with a regular expression then parse it.